# Three quarters of the page goes blank - MS-Word 2016 Windows 10-64bit SurfaceBook

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, multiple-monitors, 64-bit

Please see the attached screenshot, it happens when an external monitor is hooked up to the mini display port. The MS-Word has no problem when it's placed on the external monitor, but it shows such problem when the MS-Word is placed on the laptop monitor (with an external monitor hooked up).

With no external monitor connected via the mini display port, there is no such problem either.

(No docking station is used in either case)

Could anyone please help? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, first let's do the obvious: Check your windows updates, and especially video driver updates and make sure you are up to date (these fix problems like these).

Secondly, try minimizing the window, and resizing it a few times. I find a lot of video driver bug "Screen scooge" goes away if you do that. Covering the window up and uncovering it helps too. Once you do that, usually the problem doesn't come back.

To make it display faster, Word and many other products keep a copy of the screen in memory, and due to bugs sometimes that copy is blanked out. Moving the screen around or resizing it will force that copy to be updated, getting rid of the blank area.

Hope that helps,

== John ==